# Libgdx Android – Process has died with no erros

Tags: android, libgdx

In the middle of the game, it closes without showing any erros. 
How to identify what is causing this behavior?
I removed all exit commands on the code and still closes.

LogCat:

All Messages:

```
 05-20 09:21:16.785: I/ActivityManager(27603): Process com.xxxx.yyyy.android (pid 13684) has died.
```

On the process (PID 13684):
No errors.
No warnings.
No messages, just the normal game System.out

If I just close the game, the message on LogCat is the same.

Another device shows the errors on logCat of the process:
Note: the file numbers/2.png is ok and normally used on the Game.

```
 05-21 08:00:54.398: E/libutils.threads(14116): androidCreateRawThreadEtc     failed (entry=0x4017cf20, res=11, errno=0)

 05-21 08:00:54.398: E/libutils.threads(14116): (android threadPriority=-16)

 05-21 08:00:54.708: A/libc(14116): malloc size: 695556

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 15797

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116): Process: com.dsgames.combinations2048.android, PID: 14116

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: numbers/2.png

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:148)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.xxxx.yyyy.GameScreen.touchDown(GameScreen.java:2573)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer.touchDown(InputMultiplexer.java:90)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:375)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:470)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1527)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1244)

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error loading pixmap: decoder init failed for stream

 05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.<init>(Gdx2DPixmap.java:90)

05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:146)

05-21 08:00:55.218: E/AndroidRuntime(14116):    ... 10 more
05-21 08:00:59.698: E/AndroidGraphics(14116): waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

I discovered the problem. Every click on the screen, I created a new texture without making a dispose of the others. It was memory usage issue.
I think the line A / libc (14116): malloc size: 695 556 indicates this.

The question that remains is:
Why in one device did not generate error, only closed the game?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the onPause method of Activity and run in debug mode. When it hits the onPause method, look at the stack and see what triggered the activity to close.

Comment: onPause in GameScreenClass or AndroidLauncher?

Comment: AndroidLauncher is the Activity.

Comment: I tested it, but it closes without calling the onPause. It also does not occur error. Any idea?